What could be a possible reason for a server within a local network not being accessible as external domain?
I have a domain name "example.com" that points to my public IP (80.92.102.112). The router connected to the internet (192.168.0.1) forwards specific ports to a router within the network working in WISP mode (192.168.1.1 / 192.168.0.123). That router has a DMZ configured, redirecting all connections to a server (192.168.1.123).
I can connect to "example.com" from outside of the network and from devices connected to 192.168.0.1 but from the devices connected to 192.168.1.1 I get a connection timeout. I can still connect using IP 192.168.1.123 with no issues. I can even connect to the 192.168.1.1 using it's external IP (192.168.0.123) and get redirected to the server.
What could be the cause for this?
It doesn't work for SSH, HTTPS, IMAP and SMTP, so it's not something specific to a port or protocol.

This is a very good question, but if you want the best answer, I would advise posting it on Server Fault.

Unclear: How are you connecting to various devices, when according to your description all these connections go to the server at 192.168.1.123?

@harrymc I'm not sure what you are asking about. 192.168.1.123 is one of the devices connected to the router inside the network, I can still normally connect that router and to the one exposed to the internet.

Your description says it's in DMZ so gets all connections. Perhaps you should describe your network in more detail, and how you're connecting to the various devices. Please Edit your post to add this information.

192.168.0.123 Isn’t an external IP address and does it exist outside of your network. It’s not unusual to be unable to connect to your public IP address from within your own network.

Sounds like one of your NATs isn't doing NAT Loopback (also called "Hairpin NAT" or "NAT Hairpinning") correctly.
